# How to find all IP having a PTR-DNS-Entry for a domain

Tags: dns, reverse-dns, dns.ptr

How to get a list of all IP having a PTR-record for a particular domain, e.g. mail.example.com

Goal is to have a list of IP that

```
x.y.z.a
x.y.z.b
x.y.z.c
```

are claiming to serv mail.example.com.

Comment: Your title says "PTR" records, and your question says "A" records.  These are different - which are you after?

Comment: Wrong approval of an edit. I'm looking for PTR

Comment: You question is incorrect. `PTR` records are used to get domains related to an IP address. List of IP addresses which serves `mail.example.com` are stored as `A` record.

Comment: @SuB: I'm not looking for forward resolution, but reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Use `host` in Linux to show all IP address related to a domain name.

```
sub@ubuntu:~$ host crashlytics.com
crashlytics.com has address 107.21.238.206
crashlytics.com has address 23.21.242.216
crashlytics.com has address 23.21.93.182
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
crashlytics.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
```